# search and replace on google slide refuse to work

Tags: replace, str-replace

I'm trying to replace placeholder Text with text from form or var on Google Slides using Google Script

everything looks like it working but when I open the new google slides the placeholder are not changed. Thanks.

```
function project(){

var projectname = '666'
var category = '12345'
var subtitle = '12345'
var excerpt = '12345'

 
 //PP-Slides template file, and you get it by ID
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('fileID');
 //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
//file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid')
var copy = file.makeCopy(projectname + '-' + "Project", folder).getId();
var Slides = SlidesApp.openById(copy).getSlides();

Slides.forEach(slide => requests = [{
      replaceAllText: {
        containsText: {
          text: '{{subtitle}}',
          matchCase: true
        },
        replaceText: projectname
      }
}]);

Logger.log(copy);
Logger.log(Slides);
console.log(projectname);
}
```